# Loop in loop when printing datas from mysql

Tags: php, foreach

I want to create simple poll system. I have two question and two answers. First Question has two answer but second question hasn't any answer. In a sense I want to get:

```
First question?
Answer1
Answer2

Second question?
```

But I'm getting

```
First question?
Answer1
Answer2

Second question?
Answer1 
Answer2
```

Second question need not to have Answer1 and Answer2(same with First question answers but I have two answer in mysql).

And my foreach loops.. How need i to change my loops?

```
foreach($questions->getQuestion($_GET["category"]) as $data) // Questions
{
    echo $data["question"] . "<br/>";
    foreach($questions->getAnswer($data["id"]) as $answers) // Answers
    {
        echo $answers["answer"] . "<br/>"; // This needn't print data to below of Second Question
    }
}
```

Functions:

```
public function getQuestion( $cat )
{
    if(empty($cat))
    {
        header("location:index.php");
    }

    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='" . $cat . "'";
    $data = parent::getData();
    return $data;
}

public function getAnswer( $question )
{
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE questions='" . $question .  "'";
    $data = parent::getData();
    return $data;
}
```

Datas:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [soru] => First Question
            [kategori] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [soru] => Second Question
            [kategori] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [soru] => First Question
            [kategori] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [soru] => Second Question
            [kategori] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cevap] => Answer1
            [sorular] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cevap] => Answer2
            [sorular] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cevap] => Answer1
            [sorular] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cevap] => Answer2
            [sorular] => 1
        )

)
```

*note: these datas are only example. These are data that in mysql.*

Comment: @tereško now? can you understand?

Comment: Your example code looks fine.. if there are no answers to a question, they wouldn't display. What issue are you having? Are you asking people to write the getQuestion and getAnswer method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way i can think of would be to have two queries:

1. requesting list of question form database ordered by `question_id`
2. requesting lost of all answers for all the question from list 1. ordered by `question_id`

Then on the php side of things, you match the answers to each question. It will be a single loop, since both question and answer are already ordered and there is no need to "step back".

What you will end up will be a structure like this:

```
list = [
    {
       question: "Lorem ipsum",
       answers: [
          "answer number one",
          "answer number two"
       ]
    },
    {
       question: "Cogito ergo sum",
       answers: [
          "answer number one",
          "answer number two"
          "answer number three",
          "answer number four"
       ]
    }
]
```

You should avoid querying DB for answers to each question separately. It's kinda wasteful.

Comment: @Birlikisgu , then you will have to change the "SQL code". Otherwise it will make no sense.

Comment: @Birlikisgu , there is nothing to look, just rewrite the SQL so that the questions query `JOIN`s the questions , for all question in the category, ordered by `question_id`. Or even better - make a method `getQuestions( $cat )`.

Comment: If you cannot write, then hire someone who can. StackOverflow is not a free code generator.